# How send invite to user using LinkedIn android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I create android app using LinkedIn SDK. I want send invite in email for user which does not register in network. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be part of the public API. At least it's not exposed on https://developer.linkedin.com/ and https://apigee.com/console/linkedin